# databricks / pycharm sql connection

Tags: jdbc, pycharm, databricks

I want to add my databricks hive database to pycharm. I installed the JDBC drivers etc. like described [here](https://medium.com/@helmanofer/setup-intellij-databricks-sql-connection-1d07ce5c481e).  I'm using the latest driver: DatabricksJDBC42-2.6.36.1062 downloaded from https://www.databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-download.

When I click on Test Connection I get:

[image]

Clicking on Specify Version results in:

[image]

When I enter the version number, e.g. *2.6.36* which is the driver version not the database version I get a "driver class not instantiable".

How do I get the database version number?  Anything else that I miss?  Or someone can point out a "better" HOWTO?